# Error on editing data to save in database

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am doing a record keeping system and I used data source instead of coding the whole connection, add. edit, delete, search. I searched every videos and tutorials and I only saw add, save, delete, move next, move previous. etc. but no edit. So I followed them. The data is saved, and can be deleted. But whenever I try to edit the data then click save, it says: `Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 expected 1 records`. I made sure that my database is the data source of the gridview and all of my textboxes are connected to each respective data/field. Am I missing something?

Comment: What database are you using? Most likely you are using auto-generated IDs for your records but you are not retrieving those values when inserting a record. Without the actual ID to identify a specific record, you can't update it. The best way to retrieve the ID generated by the database depends on the database.

Comment: I'm using access as my database. Should I put text box for my ID? My ID is auto-increment and I set it visibile = false in gridview

Comment: You don't have a `GridView`.  You have a `DataGridView`, or at least that's what your tags indicate.  They are two different things.  It's a pet peeve of mine when people don't use the correct names for things to save a few keystrokes when it's a great way to cause confusion and end up wasting everyone's time on something irrelevant.

Comment: Are you populating a `DataTable` and then binding that to the grid? If so then the table will generate a temporary ID that you can use before you save the new record but, once it's saved, you need to use the final ID generated by the database, which means that you need to retrieve it from the database.  Check out this thread of mine to learn how to do that: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I'll take note sir :)

Comment: Oh yes I'm doing that. I'll go take a look at your thread. Thank you very much for your help :)